# unity to xcode orientation issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I used Unity iPhone(1.7) to build an app and brought it into Xcode (3.2.3). When the game is built out, Unity creates an appController file automatically and in it, a window is created which displays the game. When I launch the game, I can clearly see when I rotate the device that the window is rotating as well. The game elements themselves do not rotate but I see an outline of a window rotating. Since it is not a view controller, I cannot use the standard orientation methods. Before building out from Unity, the game was set to Landscape Left and the info.plist is set to the same so I am a little confused as to why I see a window rotating. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I fixed it by commeting out: iphone::KeyboardOnScreen::Init();